# How to clone a huge repo from git

Tags: gerrit, git-bash

Repo size : **15GB**

Tried cloning :

**git clone ssh://user@localhost:29418/Repo**

But it fails with :

**remote: Counting objects: 983937, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (983937/983937)
fatal: internal server error248/983937), 1.14 GiB | 991.00 KiB/s
remote: internal server error
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed**

Comment: check the server-side logs. And if this is really localhost, maybe clone via the filesystem directly.

Comment: Hi Thilo, It is not localhost i;e server - **git clone ssh://user@server:29418/Repo** and what do you mean by clone via filesystem directly..?

Comment: Hi Experts,                                                                                                   Is there any workaround for cloning huge git projects. Please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git clone --depth 1 reponame.git

cd reponame.git

git fetch --unshallow
```

Comment: After cloning the complete project , it is not showing any branches when I tried below command                                                                                   $git branch -r -a. Any solution..? How to get all the remote branches..?